# How to remap symbols on the right shift key (for all layouts)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

My alphanumerical key for '1' and '!' (the very left of the number keys) broke. So, I edited, against the advice in some articles, the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and remapped the '1' and '!' to the key left to it, the tilde (˜) key. The changes looked like that:

```
//key <TLDE> {  [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
key <TLDE> {    [     1,    exclam  ]   };
```

This worked fine. Then I decided to assign the tilde symbols to the right shift key, because I never use it. The file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` doesn't contain the right shift key, so after reading on the internet I decided to alter the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` and did the following changes

```
//key <RTSH> {  [ Shift_R       ]   };
key <RTSH> {    [ grave,    asciitilde      ]   };
```

So, I did just an outcomment and copy-paste of the command from the first file. Funnily enough, the second change works, but only in some circumstances. E.g. it works on the log-in screen, when I need to type my password. But after I log-in the right shift key is back to its original functionality. Also, when I try to type the `grave` sign by pressing left shift + right shift (on a standard US keyboard you get the `grave` by shift + tilde) I toggle between my different keyboard layouts, instead of writing a `grave`.

What's wrong? Why do I find in other articles the recommendation not to alter the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` or `pc` files? And how can I assign to my right shift key the symbols `grave, asciitilde`? Also, how can I make this change of the right shift key also be valid for my other keyboard layouts (e.g. German layout, Bulgarian layout a.s.o.). Thanks!